# How to provide installer variable to Background update downloader?

Tags: install4j

I'm using Install4j with auto update installer. I have defined a "Background update downloader" application under the "Installer" part. I want to start this installer from my own Java-application and I use the integration wizard to get the code. I set an installer variable (updatesUrl) as argument to the installer. The problem is that the installer ignores my value. I want to be able to provide my own values to the installer.

The "Backgroung update downloader" has a "Startup" block. My installer variable is not available inside this block. If I add a screen, that display the variable, outside of the "Startup" block, it will show the value that I provided as argument to the installer. So it seems that installer variable is not available inside the "Setup" block. Is it a bug or intended?

```java
ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication(
  "1529",
  new String[] {"-VupdatesUrl=file:///C:/somepath/updates.xml"},
  true,
  null
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `${installer:updatesUrl?:${compiler:sys.updatesUrl}}` resolves to `${compiler:sys.updatesUrl}` even though you pass  `-VupdatesUrl=file:///C:/somepath/updates.xml` on the command line is a bug and will be fixed in install4j 8.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the "?:" operator didn't work. The "Check for update" action has a field "Update descriptor URL" that default is set to `${installer:updatesUrl?:${compiler:sys.updatesUrl}}`. When I changed it to `${installer:updatesUrl}` it worked as expected.

Comment: That seems strange, what does `${installer:updatesUrl?:${compiler:sys.updatesUrl}}` resolve to in your case?

Comment: It resolves to the last part `${compiler:sys.updatesUrl}`.

Comment: Thank you, I could reproduce it, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.